# javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP: error code 65 - Object Class Violation];

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

Here in this code, I am not able to add one user to group. Here uid is user. Here cn=citizens,cn=doit,o=evault is group Full DN and also instead of member I tried with memberOf. But still it is showing same Exception.

```
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, initctx);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, myhost);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, mgrdn);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, mgrpw);
        System.out.println("Connect");
        String entryDN = "uid=datta,cn=doit,o=evault";

        // entry's attributes
        BasicAttribute cn = new BasicAttribute("cn", "datta");
        BasicAttribute sn = new BasicAttribute("sn", "kumar");
        BasicAttribute mail = new BasicAttribute("mail", "sai@xx.com");
        BasicAttribute phone = new BasicAttribute("telephoneNumber", "9704763492");
        BasicAttribute uid = new BasicAttribute("uid", "datta");
        BasicAttribute member = new BasicAttribute("member", "cn=citizens,cn=doit,o=evault");

        BasicAttribute oc = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
        oc.add("top");
        //oc.add("person");
        oc.add("groupOfNames");

        ((javax.naming.directory.Attribute) oc).add("organization");
       // ((javax.naming.directory.Attribute) oc).add("inetOrgPerson");
        ((javax.naming.directory.Attribute) oc).add("groupOfNames");

        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

        // build the entry
        BasicAttributes entry = new BasicAttributes();
        entry.put(cn);
        entry.put(sn);
        entry.put(mail);
        entry.put(phone);
        entry.put(uid);
        entry.put(member);
        entry.put(oc);


        // Add the entry
        ctx.createSubcontext(entryDN, (javax.naming.directory.Attributes) entry);
```

Here It showing error as :

```
javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP: error code 65 - Object Class Violation]; remaining name 'uid=datta,cn=doit,o=evault'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be totally confused as to whether you're adding a user, a group, an organization, or a user to a group.

The immediate problem is that `groupOfNames` doesn't extend `organization`, or *vice versa,* and they are both STRUCTURAL object classes, so you can't specify them both in the same object. It is a schema violation, just like the message says.

NB You don't need to cast `BasicAttribute` to `Attribute.`

Comment: You have to remove either `groupOfNames` or `organization`. Surely this is obvious? I do not understand your second question.

Comment: itz mean that how can i add that  user to one group,if u have code,plz share ...:)

Comment: A user is neither a `groupOfNames` nor an `organization`. It is an `inetOrgPerson` or one of its base classes. *You* need to decide which.